How do I refresh the result list without closing the select2?
when the result is not found, the text "result not found" appears and the existing data is hidden.when I delete it with backspace, the old data comes back before the combobox closes.when I click on the clear icon I made myself, how can I refresh or reset the result list like backspace without closing the combobox?.if there is no method for this, if I fix it in html, where can I access the old data?
I'm using Select2 4.1.0-beta.1

I tried these but none of them worked. thank you
$('#product').val(null).trigger('change');
$('#product').trigger('change');
$('#product').trigger('refresh');
$("#select2-product-results").parent().prev().children(".select2-search__field").val("")

I also tried this, while the combobox was opening, I threw the current data to the session and when I cleared it, I restored it from the session or from itself, but this time the combobox closes.I want it to do this without closing.
  $("#product").empty().prepend('<option selected class="placeholdered" value="">chooice..</option>').select2({
        data: $('#product').select2('data'), or Session("data")
    })


I think it would be easier for anyone to answer if you instead shared the exact html/css/js you are using to create that dropdown (select2) adding a X inside the suggestion control.. so people just need to add the correct logic to make it work correctly (minimal reproducible example)

I agree. Please click [edit] then click the button marked [<>] and make a [mcve] using <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/js/select2.min.js"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-beta.1/css/select2.min.css"  />

you may try $('.select2-search__field').val('').trigger('input').. triggering the input event after clearing the value

"the clear icon I made myself" - frame challenge: why not use the one built into [tag:jquery-select2]?  You can style it how you like easily enough.  Perhaps it doesn't do what you want (clear selection instead of clear input).
